# Selecting Sheets to copy to a new worksheet based on Cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I have Sheets renamed as "1","2","3",...,"31". I need a code to select the renamed sheets based on an interval value that would be provided on two cells on a sheet named "Email Summary". so for example, cell L13's value is 1 and M13's value is 5, the code would copy the sheets named "1","2",...,"5" to a new workbook. if cells L13 and M13's values are 8 and 15 respectively, the code would copy the sheets named "8","9",...,"15" to a new workbook.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this for starters.  I've edited it a bit to a) make it actually work :), and b) because the sheet names as numbers gave VB some issues.

```
Sub copy_stuff()
Dim intshName As Long, thatbook As Workbook, strshName As String
Set thatbook = Workbooks.Add
   On Error Resume Next

   For intshName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email Summary").Range("L13").Value _
      To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email Summary").Range("L15").Value
        strshName = Trim(Str(intshName))
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strshName).Copy after:=thatbook.Sheets(1)
    Next intshName
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: @Horthgar I'm getting an error with the code. "Compile error: Invalid outside procedure

Comment: @Horthgar It works! I just need to replace the .Copy after to .Copy before. Other than that, it's perfect. You're amazing.